# Not sure why JavaScript Array.prototype.filter approach runs faster than a second approach

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, filtering

I have two different approaches to filtering an array of objects based on an array of "active codes" that each objects attribute "indCode" is compared against. I thought the 'bucketFilter' approach would have less time complexity, and run faster, but in fact the 'basicFilter' function utilizing .filter() is faster. Need help understanding why.

```
function createTest (num) {
  const returnArray = [];
  
  for (let i = 0, end = num; i < end; i++) {
    const testObj = {},
      codeGenerate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      
    switch(codeGenerate) {
        case 1:
        testObj.indCode = '01';
        break;
      case 2:
        testObj.indCode = '02';
        break;
      case 3:
        testObj.indCode = '03';
        break;
      case 4:
        testObj.indCode = '04';
        break;
      case 5:
        testObj.indCode = '05';
        break;
      case 6:
        testObj.indCode = '06';
        break;
    }
    
    testObj.name = 'Test' + i;    
    returnArray.push(testObj);
  }
  
  return returnArray;
}

const activeCodes = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'];

const bucketFilter = (filterArr) => {   
  const buckets = [ [], [], [], [], [], [] ],
    codeIndexMap = {
      '01': 0,
      '02': 1,
      '03': 2,
      '04': 3,
      '05': 4,
      '06': 5
    },
    finalArr = [];

    console.time('bucketFiltering');
    
    // Break up into buckets
    for (let i = 0, end = filterArr.length; i < end; i++) {
        const bucketIndex = codeIndexMap[filterArr[i].indCode];
      buckets[bucketIndex].push(filterArr[i]);
    }
    
    // breakdown selected arrays and push to finalArr
    for (let i = 0, end = activeCodes.length; i < end; i++) {
        const currentCode = activeCodes[i],
        currentBucket = buckets[codeIndexMap[currentCode]];
      
      for (let j = 0,  jEnd = currentBucket.length; j < jEnd; j++) {
        finalArr.push(currentBucket[j]);
      }
    }
    console.timeEnd('bucketFiltering');
    return finalArr;
};

const basicFiltering = (filterArr) => {  
    const filteredArray = filterArr.filter((obj, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      console.time('basicFiltering');
    }
    if (index === filterArr.length -1) {
      console.timeEnd('basicFiltering');
    }
    return activeCodes.includes(obj.indCode) && obj;
  });
  
  return filteredArray;
}

const testData = createTest(4000);

const bucketFiltered =  bucketFilter(testData);
const basicFiltered = basicFiltering(testData);


console.log('%cBucket Filtering', 'color: aquamarine', bucketFiltered);
console.log('%cBasic Filtering', 'color: orange', basicFiltered);
```

As stated above, I have two functions. One is labeled basicFiltering, and just utilizes the native .filter() method. The function loops through some test data once, comparing each item against an array of active codes, and returns the object if there is a match.

The second function, is borrowed from Radix sort, and loops through once, breaking everything up into smaller "bucket" arrays based on an attribute named indCode. We then loop through an array containing the active codes utilized in the previous function as well. For each entry, pull that corresponding "bucket", and push to final array that we will flatten later. After all buckets are added, flatten and return the array.

Now this is where I'm getting confused, from my understanding, while less readable, the second function (or the bucket approach) should have less time complexity and total iterations, and thus be faster. Instead, it runs slightly slower than the first approach. I understand that .filter() is faster, I would just like someone to tell me why.

Comment: Maybe because `filter` is a native built-in?

Comment: I understand that there must be some performance benefits from filter being native. What I'm trying to understand is what is it about what is happening "under the hood" that causes the bucket approach to be (slightly) slower, despite the time complexity being less?

Comment: I would be careful with such statements. This might heavily depend on your environment e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Node.js, Deno, Cloudflare Workers …